# Trying to find numerics on Hive doesn't work with like query

Tags: hive, hiveql

I tried to use the following query to find rows with numeric values in `field1`

`SELECT field1 WHERE field1 NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`

However, that's returning me values that are alphanumeric too, like `3a3f3rdf3`

I am able to do what I was trying to do with this query.

`SELECT field1 WHERE field1 NOT RLIKE '[^0-9]'`

This works too:

`SELECT field1 WHERE cast(field1 as double) is not null`

But I'd still like to understand why the first one didn't work, principally I can't tell the difference from the query.

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE/NOT LIKE` - This is a normal string comparison operator. so `field1 NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` will not give you correct result because it will look for the string `[^0-9]` and not like a regular expression which looks for individual numbers. Referring to below screenshot, i created a tmp table with various different data. When we use `not like`, you can see only `[^0-9]` is getting excluded and everything remains.
[image: not like]

`RLIKE` - This is a regular expression string comparison operator. So the syntax you are using(RLIKE '[^0-9]') is a regex and it will show you data without all numbers correctly.
Refer to this link to know more on rlike - https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_operators.html#rlike

The last SQL will show data without all numbers because you are casting and picking up when that cast is resulting null.

Comment: I don't understand the explanation about why NOT LIKE won't work. If it looks for [^0-9] in the substring( i.e. anything that is not numeric) it should have worked correctly, and that's also kind of what the RLIKE query does.

Comment: not like is not a regular expression compare operator so it will look for exact pattern and not like regular expression you are expecting. i attached more explanation to my answer.